# how to make a container like a button in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to put a container in my application that behaves like a button, is this possible?

```
Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text('All categories'),
                          Text('All cities'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: you mean you want it to be clickable

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is recommended to use one of the [available button widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/material#Buttons).

If none fits your requirements, you can always wrap your custom container/widget with a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html).

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      // handle on tap here
    },
    child: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('All categories'),
          Text('All cities'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```